# Google Sheets Text Join to join character from columns into row

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, textjoin

have data like this

[image: table worksheet]

and want result like this

[image]

using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(D2:D<>"", {C2:C&"♠", D2:D&","}, ),
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,999^99)), "♠")), ",$", ))
```

make the result like this

[image]

Can someone figure it out, How to fix this formula?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's the difference between what you got and what you want?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Add `=SORT(...)`?

Comment: Is the issue simply that column 2 data is being treated as strings, rather than numeric, after the SPLIT function?  Using VALUE to convert those values back to numeric should solve the sort order issue, shouldn't it?  I'll try to come back to this, to figure out the formula...