# How to use ARRAYFORMULA with OFFSET?

Tags: google-sheets

Any thoughts why doesn't this work? I need the J column to be auto-populated.
It works correctly if I just stretch down the formula.
However I need it to dynamically adjust its size according to the number of elements in column G

[image]

Is that even achievable?

Comment: And how does the expected output look like? @Nidere

Comment: Please see the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMpSk5-i98TfTOTYceOj2il1TJtknCQYSAG70Fu77eY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes - all positions are fixed, I just need to translate this "card-like" table into a machine-readable classic sheet

Comment: Disregard my first example - I simplified it. I need a very simple thing: find element in source, and get a cell that is X rows and Y columns away from it. I usually do that with OFFSET, or INDEX, or INDIRECT, but they don't work with ARRAYFORMULA. I need the ARRAYFORMULA because the number of elements will vary

Comment: I've adjusted the spreadsheet for you to better understand the outcome I need

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
=QUERY(H6:H, "offset 1", 0)
```

or in array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({G6:G, QUERY(H6:H, "offset 1", 0)})
```

---

### UPDATE:

F3 cell:

```
=FILTER(B2:B; MOD(ROW(A2:A)-2; 4)=0)
```

G3 cell:

```
=FILTER(B2:B; MOD(ROW(A2:A)-3; 4)=0)
```

H3 cell:

```
=FILTER(B2:B; MOD(ROW(A2:A)-1; 4)=0)
```

I3 cell:

```
=FILTER(C2:C; MOD(ROW(A2:A); 4)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I'm trying to do: I need to find data from one list and reposition it on the other one. Please see the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMpSk5-i98TfTOTYceOj2il1TJtknCQYSAG70Fu77eY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think that I may have something that helps you.  The only weakness is that it currently uses two "helper" columns.  With some on the formula, these could be removed.  [Here is my sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brujR3aC29mHnKS6zj_zFyV1XsRTdjed-itmCDSG_-s/edit?usp=sharing).

First, I generate more of a database structure for the data, adding the element name to each row of data, where you have blanks in column A.  I also pull the "prop4" value from the second column.  If your data structure for column B and C is different then what you've shown, this formula might need adjustment.
This formula does that:

```
FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA({ 
    VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A); 
      IF(A2:A<>""; 
        {ROW(A2:A)\ A2:A}); 
      2; 1) 
 \
    IF(LEN(B2:B);
      IF(MOD(ROW(B2:B);4)=0;
        C2:C;B2:B);
        ISERROR(1/0))
  });
  LEN(B2:B))
```

The result looks like column K and L in this:
[image]

Then I use a query based formula on this intermediate result, giving the final result table.  The formula here ([found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670569/google-sheets-text-join-to-join-character-from-columns-into-row)) is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(L1:L<>""; {K1:K&"♠"\ L1:L&"~"}; );
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ;;999^99)); "♠~";1;1)); "~$"; ))
```

I tested this by adding an element "block" at the end of column A, and by deleting an element block in the middle of column A, both of which which worked fine.

Let us know if that is the result you want.  If not, please explain exactly what you expect, given your data.

[image]

Comment: I need to find data from one list and reposition it on the other one. Please see the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMpSk5-i98TfTOTYceOj2il1TJtknCQYSAG70Fu77eY/edit?usp=sharing
I need it to auto expand like ARRAYFORMULA does as I add elements to source list